# Is it poor form to use C features such as the size_t type instead of their c++ counterparts, such as std::size_t?

Tags: c++

I have recently been told that using `size_t` as declared in the global namespace is incorrect in C++, ostensibly because `size_t` is a C-feature. I looked this up and came across this question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t

The top answer makes it pretty clear that there isn't any *real* difference between `size_t` and `std::size_t`, but that leaves open the question of style and correctness.

Since I'm programming in C++, is it "wrong" to use a C feature such as `size_t` in place of the slightly longer but no better C++-specific `std::size_t`?

Comment: I never write `std::size_t` fwiw.

Comment: Every C function has an equivalent alias in the `std` namespace, but I'm yet to see any project that does consistent use the `std::` prefix for C-library calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<stddef.h>` is a 100% standard header file in C++, that provides the type `::size_t`.

As a bonus it also is standard in C.  Very nice if you're writing a header file for a library with a C-compatible interface, using `#if __cplusplus` / `extern "C" {`.

Note that the usual arguments about namespaces and naming collisions don't apply, as the Standard allows inclusion of any or all header files to introduce `::size_t`.

The only time that using `std::size_t` is "better" than `::size_t` is if you have not included `<stddef.h>` (perhaps you have `#include <cstddef>` instead).

Comment: <stddef.h> is a 100% standard header file in C++?? isn't anything with `.h` are c header?

Comment: @Bryan: It assuredly is part of the C++ Standard.  Section D.5 says "For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C++ standard library provides the 26 C headers.  Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard
library namespace by the corresponding *`cname`* header is placed within the global namespace scope."

Comment: @BryanChen: C++ inherits a lot from C, including just about the complete standard library.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Wouldn't that make `cstddef` the only 100% standard C++ header, and `stddef.h` something slightly less? Say 99.9%?

Comment: @david.pfx: No it wouldn't.  That is a normative rule, not a note, footnote, or suggestion.  C++ places different requirements on the content of `stddef.h` than C does.  And it is required for every hosted implementation.

Comment: `<stddef.h>` is **deprecated**.

Comment: @Pharap: This answer is written for C++11 and 14 and is correct.  If you want answers for C++20, ask a new question.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's nothing to do with C++20, `<stddef.h>` has been deprecated since at least C++11, possibly even C++98.

Answer (score 4):

If you care about 'the law' as laid out by the offical C++ standard then yes, it is bad to use `size_t`.

`size_t` (i.e. `::size_t`) can only be reliably included from `<stddef.h>` (and its relatives).
`<cstddef>` (and its relatives) will only guarantee the inclusion of `std::size_t` (i.e. `::std::size_t`), it will not guarantee the inclusion of `size_t`.

As of C++11 `<stddef.h>` (and its relatives) is **deprecated**, which means that the only means of acquiring `size_t` in the global namespace without explicitly bringing it into the global namespace (e.g. via `using std::size_t;`) is **deprecated**.

Deprecated library features could be removed in any future version of the standard library (and indeed some have been in the past), so it is bad practice to use deprecated features if you can avoid doing so.

Furthermore if you are using `<cstddef>` (or its relatives) and expecting to get `size_t` then your code is technically *not standard C++* because it is relying on an implementation-specific detail.

---

To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers):

> For some of the C standard library headers of the form `xxx.h`, the C++ standard library both includes an identically-named header and another header of the form `cxxx` (all meaningful `cxxx` headers are listed above).
>
> With the exception of `complex.h` , each `xxx.h` header included in the C++ standard library places in the global namespace each name that the corresponding `cxxx` header would have placed in the `std` namespace.
>
> These headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the `std` namespace, and the corresponding `cxxx` headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the global namespace: including `<cstdlib>` definitely provides `std::malloc` and may also provide `::malloc`. Including `<stdlib.h>` definitely provides `::malloc` and may also provide `std::malloc`. This applies even to functions and function overloads that are not part of C standard library.

Comment: You are saying they are deprecated solely because they are in Annex D, correct?  It's possible that other parts of Annex D could be removed in a future version of the Standard, but this part NEVER will be... reading Annex D of the Standard as if only for "backward" compatibility is wrong, as all cross-compatibility and forward-compatibility concerns end up there.  This particular one is necessary in new header files that can be included into both C and C++ context... which means the public header file of practically every library in the world.

Comment: @BenVoigt Annexe D specifically defines deprecated as "Normative for the current edition of the Standard, but not guaranteed to be part of the Standard in future revisions"/"Normative for the current edition of this International Standard, but having been identified as a candidate for removal from future revisions" and includes the C standard library headers. You can make any argument as to why the standards committee will never remove it, but unless the committee has outright stated "we will never remove them" or later undeprecates them, any conjectural argument is irrelevant.

Comment: According the same reference, C++23 has undeprecated xxx.h headers. From cppreference: "xxx.h headers are deprecated in C++98 and undeprecated in C++23. These headers are discouraged for pure C++ code, but not subject to future removal."